# Sending Email with PDF attachment from button in PDF Form

Tags: javascript, java, email, pdf, email-attachments

I have been attempting to code a button into my adobe PDF form using an article from quora. The goal is to click a button and it opens an email box with the "to", "subject line", "body" and the "PDF" attaching to the email without having to save the pdf somewhere locally on the clients computer.

These are the three different codes I have found and attempted to use. No matter what I do, I end up getting an "Unterminated String Literal" on line 3 where the body field starts. I have tried adding/removing everything I can think of. ;"'{{:.

Please help if you can! See code below.

var customSubject = this.getField("MyTextField").value;
var mailtoUrl = "mailto:email@email.com?subject=" + Information Form;
this.submitForm({Thank you for your considerate attention to the attached pdf. Let me know if you need anything.; further.
cURL: mailtoUrl, cSubmitAs: "PDF" });

var customSubject = this.getField("MyTextField").value;
var mailtoUrl = "mailto:email@email.com=" + Information Form;
this.submitForm({Thank you for your considerate attention to the attached pdf. Let me know if you need anything.
cURL: mailtoUrl, bPDF:true});

var cToAddr = "email@email.comm"
var cSubLine = "Information Form - " + this.getField(No1LastName) + ", " + this.getField(No2LastName) + "
var cBody = "Please find the attached Information Form. Thank you for your considerate attention to the attached."
this.mailDoc({bUI: true, cTo: cToAddr, cSubject: cSubLine, cMsg: cBody});

Answer (score 0):

I found that declaring a variable for the email portion worked. I was able to include custom to, cc, subject, and body, as well as attaching the PDF.

```
var customREmail = this.getField("ReqEmail").value;
var customAEmail = this.getField("AgyEmail").value;
var customAgency = this.getField("Agency").value;
var customLName = this.getField("Lease").value;
var customBAddr = this.getField("BldgAddr").value;
var customBCity = this.getField("BldgCity").value;
var mailtoUrl =
 "mailto:XXX@XXX.XXX?cc=" +
 customREmail +
 "; " +
 customAEmail +
 "&subject=Compliance%20Request: " +
 customAgency +
 ", "  +
 customLName +
 " - " +
 customBAddr +
 ", " +
 customBCity +
 "&body=Please review the attached request.%0A%0AThank you,%0A%0A";
this.submitForm({
 cURL:mailtoUrl, cSubmitAs:"PDF", bPDF:true
});
```